# Передача исключений на уровень выше

Tags: c#, исключения

Создал свой класс исключения

```
    public class HTML_Manager_Exception : ApplicationException
    {
        public HTML_Manager_Exception() { }
        public HTML_Manager_Exception(string message) : base(message) { }
        public HTML_Manager_Exception(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected HTML_Manager_Exception(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
    }
```

Есть у меня два метода:

```
   public static async void BonusTableRefresh(int u_id)
        {           
            try
            {
                LoginBon(u_id);
            }
            catch (HTML_Manager_Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HTML_Manager_Exception(ex.Message);                
            }                
         }

  public static async void LoginBon(int u_id)
        {
            string login = CryMotherFucker.DecryptStringAES(du["log_bonus"].ToString(), CryMotherFucker.SharedSecret);           
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
                throw new HTML_Manager_Exception("Для пользователя не указан логин доступа к сайту");
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы при выбрасывании исключения в методе LoginBon оно передавалось в метод BonusTableRefresh, но этого почему-то не происходит, прога просто стопится. В чём дело?

Comment: Вы не можете передать исключение в метод, который не ждет результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваши методы действительно асинхронны, то вам и нужно их вызывать как асинхронные, с ожиданием результата выполнения. В частности, вместо

```
LoginBon(u_id);
```

напишите

```
await LoginBon(u_id);
```

А тип возвращаемого значения для него замените с void на Task. 
Также если метод `CryMotherFucker.DecryptStringAES` является асинхронным, то и перед ним нужен оператор `await`.